# How can I use Mininet Python API to send UDP packets from one host to another?

Tags: python, sockets, mininet

Firstly,in SingleSwitchTopo.py, I set up a network containing 2 hosts and 1 switch. Ping and iperf between h1 and h2 are OK. Then I let h1 runs server.py, it serves as a server. h2 runs client.py, it sends UDP packets to h1, then h1 will receive data and write to a file. But why can't h1 get data from h2? How to do this correctly?

SingleSwitchTopo.py

```
from mininet.topo import Topo
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.util import dumpNodeConnections
from mininet.log import setLogLevel
from mininet.node import CPULimitedHost
from mininet.link import TCLink

class SingleSwitchTopo(Topo):
    "Single switch connected to n hosts."
    def build(self, n=2):
        switch = self.addSwitch('s1')
        for h in range(n):    
            host = self.addHost('h%s' % (h + 1), cpu=.6/n)     
            self.addLink(host, switch, bw=500, delay='10ms', loss=10, max_queue_size=100, use_htb=True)

def simpleTest():
    "Create and test a simple network"
    topo = SingleSwitchTopo(n=2)
    net = Mininet(topo=topo, host=CPULimitedHost, link=TCLink)
    net.start()
    h1 = net.get('h1')
    h2 = net.get('h2')
    h1.cmd('kill %python')
    h2.cmd('kill %python')
    h1.cmd('python server.py &')
    h2.cmd('python client.py %s ' % h1.IP())
    net.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setLogLevel('info')
    simpleTest()
```

server.py

```
import socket
address = ('127.0.0.1', 9999)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(address)
f = open('/home/knshen/a.txt', 'w+')

while True:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    print 'data', data
    f.write(data)
    f.flush()
f.close()
s.close()
```

client.py

```
import socket
import sys
from time import sleep

address = (sys.argv[1], 9999)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
i = 1
while True:
    s.sendto('hi : %d\n' % i, address)
    i += 1
    sleep(3)

s.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set up a client server using iperf commands.

Start xterms for both server(h1) and client (h2) by using

```
xterm h1 h2
```

Then in h1 run

```
iperf -s -u -i 1
```

to start a udp server which sends packets with an interval of 1 second

Then in h2 run

```
iperf -c 10.0.0.1 -u -b 1m -n 1000
```

which creates a udp client that connects to h1 at address 10.0.0.1, bandwidth = 1M, number of bytes to transport = 1000

Here is a link showing various iperf parameters/features
http://openmaniak.com/iperf.php

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a late answer, [here](https://gist.github.com/bocon13/6056675) there's a simple but effective solution.

Many thanks to Brian O'Connor for the code.